# Parse json object with back slashes and add it back into the data json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

Just wondering, in the `JSON` below, is it possible to parse through the single object call 'Data', remove the back slashes, separate each key value pairs in the single object, and then append it back into the original JSON data.

This:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-14T20:02:57.000Z",
  "Data": "{\"UserId\":\"00529000001jD4uAAE\",\"CardElement\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityLabel\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityName\":\"Contract Account\",\"TrackingEvent\":\"Field\",\"TrackingService\":\"VCards\"}",
  "CustomerInteractionId": "a1629000000VQgvAAG",
  "Vlocity Tracking Entry Name": "Field"
}
```

Turns into this:

```
 {
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-14T20:02:57.124Z",
  "CustomerInteractionId": "a1629000000VQgvAAG",
  "Vlocity Tracking Entry Name": "Field",
  "UserId": "00529000001jD4uAAE",
  "CardElement": "Total Due",
  "EntityLabel": "Contract Account",
  "TrackingEvent": "Field",
  "TrackingService": "VCards"
}
```

Having some issues breaking it down to their own key value pairs and appending it back into the `JSON`. Can be in `JS` or `AngularJS`

Comment: check my answer below :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   

var datas = {
  "Timestamp": "2018-05-14T20:02:57.000Z",
  "Data": "{\"UserId\":\"00529000001jD4uAAE\",\"CardElement\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityLabel\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityName\":\"Contract Account\",\"TrackingEvent\":\"Field\",\"TrackingService\":\"VCards\"}",
  "CustomerInteractionId": "a1629000000VQgvAAG",
  "Vlocity Tracking Entry Name": "Field"
};

datas = Object.assign({}, datas, JSON.parse(datas.Data));
delete datas.Data;
console.log(datas);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data` is a string in your JSON. You can selectively parse your string and then create a new object with parsed `Data` and original object. Then remove the `Data` from the new object.

```js
var res = { "Timestamp": "2018-05-14T20:02:57.000Z", "Data": "{\"UserId\":\"00529000001jD4uAAE\",\"CardElement\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityLabel\":\"Total Due\",\"EntityName\":\"Contract Account\",\"TrackingEvent\":\"Field\",\"TrackingService\":\"VCards\"}", "CustomerInteractionId": "a1629000000VQgvAAG", "Vlocity Tracking Entry Name": "Field" },
  result = {...res, ...JSON.parse(res.Data)};
delete result.Data;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ah, isee. Yes, this works. Will read up on parsing some more. Thanks @Hassan!

Comment: @PeterHoang, this is entirely different from what you asked.